# Maximize taking too long

Tags: mathematical-optimization, maximum

I just started to use Mathematica a few weeks ago. I am afraid there is something that does not work on my laptop because, for the following simple command, it takes too much time. Do you know if there is a mistake in this command syntax?

```
Maximize[
  {(g/e)*Sqrt[((g - e)^2 + (f - h)^2)], 
   0 <= e <= 1, 0 <= f <= 1, e^2 + f^2 == 1, 0 <= g <= e,  0 <= h <= f}, 
  {e, f, g, h}]
```

Comment: Use NMaximize. Also your constraint 0<=e<=1  implies I can make e as close to zero as I want and (g/e) will blow up to infinity regardless of the other constraints. If there were a positive lower bound on g, f, or e then this wouldn't be the case.

Comment: As `e` approaches zero, the constraints require `g` to also. The objective can be maximized in the limit as `g -> e`: `Maximize[{Limit[obj, g -> e], cons}, {e, f, g, h}]` evaluates to  `{1, {e -> 0, f -> 1, g -> 0, h -> 0}}`